# Usage of function clGetExtensionFunctionAddress

Tags: opencl

I'm new to OpenCL extensions and I try to use the extension function **clImportMemoryARM** witht code blow:

```
cl_mem buffer = NULL;
clImportMemoryARM = (clImportMemoryARMFunc)clGetExtensionFunctionAddressForPlatform(plt->platforms[0], "clImportMemoryARM");
buffer = clImportMemoryARM(plt->context[0], 0, NULL, NULL, 0, &ret);
```

But I recieved the error ***‘clImportMemoryARMFunc’ was not declared in this scope*** in build, and I changed *clImportMemoryARMFunc* with clImportMemoryARM also recieved the error message ******error: assignment of function ‘_cl_mem* clImportMemoryARM(cl_context, cl_mem_flags, const cl_import_properties_arm*, void*, size_t, cl_int*)**. I just don't konw how to use the function like this, could any tech-savvy can solve the problem?

**Thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because the driver did not expose **clImportMemoryARM** to user so you have to define a **function pointer** youself like this:

```
typedef cl_mem(clImportMemoryARM_func)
(cl_context                     psContext,
cl_mem_flags                    bfFlags,
const cl_import_properties_arm *properties,
void *                          pvMemory,
size_t                          uiSize,
cl_int *                        piErrorCodeRet);
```

and then you can use function pointer to this API,like this:

```
clImportMemoryARM_func *clImportMemoryARM = NULL;

clImportMemoryARM = (clImportMemoryARM_func *)clGetExtensionFunctionAddressForPlatform(plt->platforms[0], "clImportMemoryARM");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `cl_ext.h`:

```
#include <CL/cl_ext.h>
```

This file is part of OpenCL headers. This header should have all extensions which don't have "external dependencies" (like e.g OpenGL), and it also has `clImportMemoryARM` and a bunch of other ARM functions and declarations.